# Конвертировать файл с кодировкой Macintosh в доступный Windows формат

Tags: кодировка, конвертация

Достал файл, notepad++ показал, что кодировка макинтош.
Слова на англ есть, всё остальное - кракозябры. Как перевести в виндепонятный формат для правки?

Comment: enconv в помощь. Но вообще близко к оффтопику.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй [декодер кодировки](https://www.artlebedev.ru/tools/decoder/advanced/), потом открой файл с нужной кодировкой (MS Word точно поддерживает открытие файла с другой кодировкой в читабельном виде).
Есть также [онлайн-декодеры](http://2cyr.com/decode/?lang=ru).